# TFS Merge does not always adopt most recent page in application - changes are lost

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge, tfvc

I've been bitten by a strange (IMO) behaviour in TFS today.  This is the third time I've seen this in the three years I've been using TFS.  It's best explained with an illustration...

[image]

I have an `In-progress` branch of a webforms project, that is used for quick bug fixes and small changes.  From that, I do a branch for larger development projects.

Last week a customer reported a bug on `Page123.aspx`.  We did a branch, fixed the bug, and merged `Bug fix` branch back to `In-Progress` branch. All changes were committed at each stage.

This week we deployed to the live system from `In-Progress`, only the see the bug had mysteriously come back.

At no point on the `In-progress` branch was `Page123.aspx` modified.  When I compared local/server versions, the server version had the fixed page, and the local version was still buggy.  However, I am the only developer, so I don't understand how this could happen.

When I branched again from `In-Progress` to `New dev branch`, the buggy `Page123.aspx` obviously remained.

The only way to force my TFS/VS2013 to remember the fix was to do a *Get Specific Version* on `Page123.aspx` to replace the local version with the server version.

Is there some kind of bug in TFS that causes this, or is it stupidity?  99% of the time merging correctly gets the latest version of every page.

Comment: Did you use gated check-in? Did you clear the Preserve my pending changes locally check box?

Comment: I don't think so.  This is VS2015.3 linked to TFS on VisualStudio.com.  I don't see those options, so presume that this hasn't been the case.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you use GIT version control? Did you use Pull Request? Could you share the steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: No its TF Version Control, not GIT.  I can't actually reproduce on-demand due to the intermittent nature of the problem.

Comment: Did you check the history of your local version and compare it to server version to see if there is some changeset missed in your local version?